# How can I generate multiple trendlines on a single graph?

Tags: r, time-series, trendline

I currently have time series data in the form of abundance values over time, specifically sea turtle abundance values in the form of nest counts per year. Each individual strand of abundance values refers to a particular rookery (i.e. location). Each individual rookery is, however, located within a different geographic region. So, in other words, I have time series data for individual rookeries, and a collection of rookeries is located within a particular geographic area. For example, lets say I have the following data available in a dataframe:

| **Region** | **Rookery** | **Number of nests** | **Year** |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Indian Ocean | South Africa | 25 | 1999 |
| Indian Ocean | South Africa | 30 | 2000 |
| Indian Ocean | South Africa | 35 | 2001 |
| Indian Ocean | Mozambique | 10 | 2000 |
| Indian Ocean | Mozambique | 5 | 2001 |
| Atlantic Ocean | Brazil | 120 | 2000 |
| Atlantic Ocean | Brazil | 130 | 2001 |
| Atlantic Ocean | Brazil | 100 | 2002 |
| Atlantic Ocean | Argentina | 1000 | 2001 |
| Atlantic Ocean | Argentina | 1200 | 2002 |
| Atlantic Ocean | Argentina | 5000 | 2003 |

Consider the above dataframe (this is only a subset of the very large dataset at my disposal). What I would like to do is create a single graph showing the trend in abundance (i.e. trendlines) at the **Region** level. So, on a single plot, I would have *year* as my independent variable (i.e. on x-axis) and *Number of nests* as my dependent variable (i.e. on y-axis). I would then like to have a single trendline for abundance for the Indian Ocean region, and another trendline for abundance in for the Atlantic Ocean region (on a single graph).

Ultimately, it would also be beneficial to be able to generate an OVERALL trendline that takes all of the **region** trendlines together.

Any help would greatly be appreciated :)

Comment: It looks like the scale of your data differs greatly by region, at least in this example. You may consider [faceting](https://r4ds.had.co.nz/data-visualisation.html#facets) your plot by region instead of including all regions on the same plot. This would allow you to use different y-axis ranges for each region. If forced to use the same y-axis, any trends in regions with small number of nests may be obscured.

Comment: Thank you @zephryl, I will definitely check it out :)

Answer (score 0):

Trendlines as in simple regression line and not `geom_line()`

```
library(tidyverse)
library(ggplot2)

df %>% 
  ggplot() + 
  aes(x = Year, y = Number_of_nests, col = Region) +
  geom_smooth(method = "lm", se = TRUE)
```

[image]

Comment: Is there a way to keep the individual rookeries separate on the graph with an overall trendline for them? In the above graph it appears that the values for Brazil and Argentina, for example, are "attached" in the trendline

Comment: @SHoekstra try adding `geom_point() +` before the line starting `geom_smooth(...`